# how to do a search query in mongoose with various parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, search, mongoose

I created a Jobs API now I want to make a search functionality with skills and location.  Example, If I search with the skills HTML, CSS, JavaScript and with the particular location then it should display the list of Jobs that matches the query.

JSON Data:

```
{
    "jobID": 1245,
    "title": "Front-End Developer",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."
    "Skills": "JavaScript, jQuery, Angular.js, React.js, Ember.js",

},
{
    "jobID": 2982,
    "title": "Back-End Developer",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."
    "Skills": "JavaScript, Node.js, Express.js, MongoDB"
},
{
    "jobID": 5782,
    "title": "Full-Stack Developer",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."
    "Skills": "JavaScript, jQuery, Angular.js, backbone.js"
},
{
    "jobID": 4674,
    "title": "Java Developer",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."
    "Skills": "Java, J2EE, JSON, JBOSS, Spring, Hibernate"
},
{
    "jobID": 1589,
    "title": "Hadoop Developer",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."
    "Skills": Hadoop, Spark, Teradata, Scala, Oozie, Java,  etc."
}
```

{
    "jobID": 1245,
    "title": "Front-End Developer",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."
    "Skills": "JavaScript, jQuery, Angular.js, React.js, Ember.js",
    "location": India
},
{
    "jobID": 2982,
    "title": "Back-End Developer",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."
    "Skills": "JavaScript, Node.js, Express.js, MongoDB",
    "location": USA
},
{
    "jobID": 5782,
    "title": "Full-Stack Developer",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."
    "Skills": "JavaScript, jQuery, Angular.js, backbone.js",
    "location": UK
},
{
    "jobID": 4674,
    "title": "Java Developer",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."
    "Skills": "Java, J2EE, JSON, JBOSS, Spring, Hibernate",
    "location": Russia
},
{
    "jobID": 1589,
    "title": "Hadoop Developer",
    "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus."
    "Skills": Hadoop, Spark, Teradata, Scala, Oozie, Java,  etc.",
    "location": China
}

Route.js file

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express'),
    router = express.Router(),
    search = require('../controllers/search');

Router.get('/:query', search.get);

module.exports = router;
```

Search.js file

```
'use strict';
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Jobs = mongoose.model('Jobs');

var search = {

    get: function (req, res) {
        var searchQuery = req.params.query;

        Jobs.findOne({search : searchQuery}, function(err, result) {
            if (err)  throw err;
            console.log(result);
            res.json(result);
        });
    }

};

module.exports = search;
```

Server.js file

```
'use strict';
var express = require('express'),
    app = express();

//Routes
var jobRoute = require('./routes/router');
app.use('/api/jobs', jobRoute);

//Search Routes
var searchRoute = require('./routes/search-route');
app.use('/api/search', searchRoute);

//Server Connection
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port 8080!');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
Jobs.find({skill: "html",location:"US"}, function(err, user) 
 {
    if (err)
    {
        res.send(err);
    }
  }


 });
```

Comment: How about the router params how I should pass ?

Comment: Sorry, dint get your question.

Comment: My Route.js and search.js files had correct code? Is that the correct way to write it?

Comment: GET /search?q=skill=html&location=US.. something like this

Comment: Seems okay to me!

Comment: In express.js Is this the way to write ?
Route path: /users/:userId/books/:bookId
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/users/34/books/8989
req.params: { "userId": "34", "bookId": "8989" }

Answer (score 0):

To make a search with multiple parameters, you can separate it by comma

```
Jobs.find({location:"wherever",skills:{$in:["Java","Javascript"]}}, function(err, data) {
    //your code
}
```

The `$in` parameter takes an array as argument and will return all the documents that contains one of the fields on the array.

Comment: If I pass in this way I'm getting an empty array [ ] in data.

Comment: What's the name of your collection in the database? Case sensitive please

Comment: I found the problem it was because of case sensitive!

Comment: I see, do you mind at least upvoting my answer then?

Comment: No, I can upvote yours because of fewer reputations. To upvote, we must have at least 15 reputations.